# Get logged in user by searching cakephp 2.x session table

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I wanted to use the session table to get a list of all logged in users.  To do this I attempted to use the following code to query the cake_sessions table:

```
$this->loadModel('CakeSession');
$sessions = $this->CakeSession->find('all', array('fields' => 'data'));
// next I process session data to find logged in users
```

But running this code I get the following error:

**Call to undefined method CakeSession::find()**

If I use the following code to directly access the table it works just fine:

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource("default");
$sessions = $db->fetchAll("SELECT data from cake_sessions");
// next I process session data to find logged in users
```

Is accessing the session table restricted?  My current solution works just fine but I am confused why I cant use the the CakeSession->find().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CakeSession is **not** a model class. See 
http://api.cakephp.org/2.8/class-CakeSession.html

The class you refer to is a **datasource** as the "namespace" tells you as well: `Cake\Model\Datasource`. In Cake2 session access was implemented as datasource. "Model" is a layer not just a single type of files.

Create a proper session model class in your apps Model folder. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html

You might have to name it different to avoid conflicts because Cake2 is not using real php namespaces unlike Cake3.

Comment: thanks!  That explains it.  I hadnt created a model because I assumed that a call to **$this->loadModel('CakeSession');** would dynamically create the model for me.  But that name must have been causing a conflict.  When I create a new model called MyCakeSession it works just fine.